# Exporting from CloudSQL with where clause, during runtime

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mysql, database-backups

environment: Google App Engine, Java, jdbc, CloudSQL

I need to export a subset of rows, so they can be imported by other applications (be they GAE or other)(or me, at a later time).

mysqldump does the job (with --where= ) but I want my application to do it in runtime (and I don't know how to use it in GAE)

The CloudSQL API only exports whole databases. Suggestions? What should I be looking into? Other than .execute() a prepared statement.

Comment: can you post seome code or jsfiddle?

Comment: Thank you for spotting a new user and pointing me to community and common sense guidelines. What do you need a jsfiddle for? I'm not asking for code, and my case doesn't need a HTML/CSS/JS sandbox. [This](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta3/instances/export) is the export that GAE has. My question is 'how can I export selected rows to a file, at runtime'. 'mysqldump' does what I want, but I don't know how to run it inside GAE. I think this is a reasonable question and is properly stated.